# Interpret residuals in random and fixed effects models in meta-analysis

Tags: residuals, meta-analysis

How to interpret residuals in random and fixed effects models? I am a medical doctor. Kindly explain in simple words.
**Updated** Here is an example:

```
Weight (Fixed)      Weight (Random)    Residual (Fixed)      Residual (Random)
Relative weight    Relative weight     Std Residual         Std Residual

32.27                21.56               -4.61                -1.62
25.14                21.02               -0.41                -0.46
18.52                20.21               2.16                  0.52
14.39                19.39               2.10                  0.62
 9.68                17.81               2.56                  1.04
```

Comment: it would help us if you can tell us which software you used and some sample commands. At the moment, I think, we can only guess because outputs are _sometimes_ software dependent.

Comment: @suncoolsu: Thank you for your help. I have used Comprehensive meta analysis v2. Run analysis was the command used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @suncooolsu has already pointed out, we need more information. Residuals are often used when it comes to identifying outliers and to gain a better understanding of the appropriateness of a certain model (here: FEM vs REM). Given your "Std Residual", I would say that a REM seems more appropriate. However, you definitely might want to check other heterogeneity tests (e.g., Q, I^2).

Recently Viechtbauer/Cheung (2010) have published a really nice article on "[Outlier and influence diagnostics for meta-analysis](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jrsm.11/abstract)" (see esp. section 3).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have included the other results herewith. Q-value-28.056, df (Q) 4.000 ,  P-value 0.000 , I-squared 85.743

Comment: @DrWho I would only report the results based on the random effects model (I mean, I would always report the REM results, regardless of the actual test statistics...).